# In a RecyclerView, pass the opposite dragging motion event to view below it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, motionevent

**Current Layout** (pseudo)

```
<Layout ..... >

<BottomSheet ..../>

<RecyclerView
  orientation="horizontal"/>

</Layout>
```

[Video of layout interaction](https://i.gyazo.com/88d677533186251d726f789fae7be288.mp4)

**The Issue**
The bottom sheet peaks out over the horizontal recycler view, where a user can drag up on it and have the sheet be displayed. When the sheet is hidden, the recycler view above it consumes all touches including vertical dragging. So the user is forced to accurately find the 5dp peaking section to drag up.

**Question**
How can I override the recycler view to pass vertical drags to the view below it (bottom sheet)

**Initial Attempts**
Even if I return false for `onItemTouch` or `onTouchIntercepted` the vertical touch isn't passed to the view below it, so I believe I'm missing a core concept behind touch events.